# Select2 option templateResult not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I would like to use [templateResult](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating) option to format my results using select2 v4. I have the following code:

```
$(".search").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data.items
            };
        },
        templateResult: function (data) {
            console.log('templateResult');
            return '<span><img src="//example.com/img.png" /> ' + data.text + '</span>';
        },
    }
});
```

However, `templateResult` doesn't appear to be getting called as nothing is outputted to the console. Even if I change the return to 'TEST', the default results are still displayed. The code works the same whether I include the templateResult or not.

Comment: Odd - it seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/waxt54cv/.

Comment: Thanks - that's without the ajax call but it helped me spot the issue. The templateResult option was inside the ajax callback.

Comment: Ahh yes! I missed that myself. Glad you got it working

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the templateResult inside ajax scope. Fix is below:

```
$(".search").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data.items
            };
        },
    },
    templateResult: function (data) {
        console.log('templateResult');
        return '<span><img src="//example.com/img.png" /> ' + data.text + '</span>';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `processResults - results: data.items`, I switched to `data.results`

Comment: It would be better you could please elaborate a bit more on this in a nicely formatted way.